# Swarga / Narak ( on domestic animals)

Tags: vedas, puranas, upanishads, swarga, naraka

Famous religious orator Devkinandan Thakur Ji Maharaj has spoken that if we keep domestic animals like DOGS, CAT AND PIGS in our house we will go to Narak.

And whatever religious things we do will become useless

So according to PURANAS is this true ??

Comment: according to puranas we should help every needy.. and animals are the most needy creature on earth.. so definitly we can pet them... narak and swarg are alloted by your karma.